# How do you remove margin/padding from a GraphViz node using an image?

Tags: graphviz

I am using GraphViz with user defined shapes for nodes using the image tag.  The images are png files, and contain lines to the edge of the image to link up with edges drawn by GraphViz.  But if I try to make a rudimentary graph using neato with a defined layout, you can still see some margin or padding between the images and the graph edges that show up as small gaps in the lines.  There is no border in the images themselves.  (I also need to re-center some of the images.)  How does one remove the gaps?

Here is my .dot, with several attempts inspired by other answers, but nothing seems to remove the gaps.

```
graph G {

  pad = 0.0; 

  a  [ label="",  pos="0,0",       shape=none,      width=0, height=0, image="LnLft.png"     ];
  b  [ label="",  pos="100,0",     shape=none,      width=0, height=0, image="BrkClsHrz.png", penwidth=0 ];
  h1 [ label="",  pos="200,0",     shape=none,      width=0, height=0                        ];
  c  [ label="",  pos="200,-100",  shape=plaintext, width=0, height=0, image="BrkClsVrt.png", penwidth=0 ];
  d  [ label="",  pos="200,-200",  shape=plaintext, width=0, height=0, image="BrkOpnVrt.png" ];
  h2 [ label="",  pos="200,-300",  shape=none,      width=0, height=0                        ];
  e  [ label="",  pos="100,-300",  shape=none,      width=0, height=0, image="BrkClsHrz.png", margin="0,0"];
  f  [ label="",  pos="0,-300",    shape=none,      width=0, height=0, image="LnLft.png"     ];
  a -- b  [len=1.5, penwidth=2];
  b -- h1 [len=1.5, penwidth=2];
  h1 -- c [len=1.5, penwidth=2];
  c -- d  [len=1.5, penwidth=2];
  d -- h2 [len=1.5, penwidth=2];
  h2 -- e [len=1.5, penwidth=2];
  e -- f  [len=1.5, penwidth=2];
}
```

And here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Is it necessary to include part of the edge in the image?

Comment: pad applies to the margin around the entire graph, not nodes.  Are you sure the image does not include a border?  You might try shapefile (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/shapefile/) attribute instead of image.  Deprecated, but might do what you want.